# Updating from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.3

Tags: php

I am currently on PHP 7.1 and wish to upgrade to PHP 7.3. Is it recommended to upgrade directly from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.3? Or is it the recommended way to upgrade to PHP 7.2 first and then to PHP 7.3? In case I have to upgrade to 7.2 first and then to 7.3, then may I know the reason why I can't skip 7.2?

Comment: count, each, create_function is deprecated in 7.2 as well as 7.3. https://www.cnblogs.com/phpnew/p/7991572.html I will skip 7.2

Comment: What are you even asking about? Upgrading PHP in Apche/Nginx/...? Or making a PHP application run on newer version? Or perhaps something else entirely? Please provide some context.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in migrating from 7.1 to 7.3

But if you have any applications which relies on the features of 7.1 where some of them are deprecated in 7.3, you will find it a problem to run your applications.

Therefore the best is to refer the PHP 7 ChangeLog before migrating => https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php

If your OS is Ubuntu you may follow below steps:
https://medium.com/andrewmmc-io/upgrade-php-version-to-7-2-from-7-0-c005a0926642